# Vectorization of a for loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, vectorization

I am working on a stock market price analysis project and would like to find the day open price (regular market hours) utilizing 1 minute data.  Some stocks analyzed may not have any trades at the 9:31 row in the data, so no value would be added for the day in those cases.  Thus, I had to write a for loop to capture the first price of the day after the 9:31 row just in case there is not a value there.  I am looking to avoid a 'for' loop in this instance and would like to receive suggestions of more efficient code (perhaps vectorization) to capture the first open value if none exist on the 9:31 row.

```
A = a_df
A = A.between_time('9:31', '16:00')
A["D"] = A["T"].dt.date
dates = A.D.unique().tolist()

N = A[0:0]
for i in dates:
    temp = A.loc[A.Date == i].iloc[-1]
    N = N.append(temp,ignore_index=False)
N.index = N.index.date
N = N [['open']]
N.rename(columns = {'open':'Day'}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Please provide code for a mimum reproducible example.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your feedback.  I attempted to break it down, but it is still a bit long.  The problem here is that I don't know how to minimize it and still make it work.